# sending one attachment

Tags: php, attachment, mailer

I am sending a single attachment with an email message using the following code. I use the phpmailer class: I know it's a very simple and easy thing, but it is not working.

This is my php call;

```
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['attach']['name']);
```

This is my html;

```
<form id="Form" name="Form" method="POST" action="<?php $PHP_SELF ?>"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="attach" name="attach" type="file" />
```

I am sending an email with it too. The email is sent, but the attachment is not. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encapsulate your code with error checking code so you know whether or not it worked:

```
if (!$mail->AddAttachment($filepath, $_FILES['attach']['name']) {
  echo "Error attaching file at $filepath. Dumping variables to output.";
  var_dump($_FILES['attach']);
}
```

Note you can't simply pass the name of the file to the the AddAttachment method; the first parameter is expected to be a path, as per the [PHPMailer API](http://www.tig12.net/downloads/apidocs/wp/wp-includes/PHPMailer.class.html#det_methods_AddAttachment). You have to figure out what that path is, and then also include the name of the file.

Comment: I have tried your code and this error results from attachments Error attaching file. Dumping variables to output.array(5) { ["name"]=> string(9) "Hibha.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phptc7B0H" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(95187) }